# A mini server component to accept large files

Tags: .net, multithreading, network-programming

We would have to accept large text files (approx. 5 GB at max) into our server. 
It needs to be able to:
 
1. accept the file and write it to server disk
2. support multiple clients
3. and, of course in case something is broken, restart its worker processes listening for clients. but not much more management is necessary
4. high performance is very important
5. resume from a given point if connection was broken (not essential)

My question is: are you aware of a(n) (open source) simple and robust component that does just that. And no dependency other than .net framework libraries (v4.5 OK)?

If not, what would be your suggestion for a start?

Thank you
K.

PS: I forgot to mention, but authentication is not needed

Comment: @Tommy Grovnes
yes, indeed. But as egrunin pointed out ftp is not known to be fast. But, more importantly, we need to be able to signal finish of the upload operation, which calls for an embedded library. Besides, we do not really need all those ftp commands be supported

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with *Tommy Grovnes* that's what FTP servers are for. If you are targeting a tight integration you could use the C# FTP Server Library project [csftpserver](http://csftpserver.sourceforge.net/).

> A C# .net library for creating customised FTP servers. It should be
>   left up to the application to determine authenication, provide
>   directory listings, and provide file data. The library should purely
>   deal with the FTP protocol using managed C#.net.

Comment: In principle, yes, but ftp is a slow protocol. And does it support interrupt/restart?

Comment: @platzhirsch: do you have experience with cftpserver?